# Upload document to Sharepoint 2013 Online using webservices

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2013

I have a client who is implementing customer portals in Sharepoint 2013 Online. The current program distributes documents to the customers by mail. Now we have to upload the documents to the customer portal.

I try to use the copy webservice in sharepoint. I created a test project and added the webservice as Web Reference and wrote the following testcode:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string baseUrl = "https://mycustomer.sharepoint.com/sites/";
    string customer = "customerportalname";
    string serviceUrl = "/_vti_bin/copy.asmx";
    string destinationDirectory = "/folder/";
    string fileName = "uploaded.xml";

    string username = "username@outlook.com";
    string password = "password";

    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml("<fiets><onderdeel>voorwiel</onderdeel><onderdeel>achterwiel</onderdeel><onderdeel>trappers</onderdeel><onderdeel>stuur</onderdeel><onderdeel>frame</onderdeel></fiets>");

    byte[] xmlByteArray;
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        xmlDocument.Save(memoryStream);
        xmlByteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    string destinationUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", baseUrl, customer, destinationDirectory, fileName);
    string[] destinationUrlArray = new string[] { destinationUrl };

    FieldInformation fieldInfo = new FieldInformation();
    FieldInformation[] fields = { fieldInfo };


    CopyResult[] resultsArray;

    using (Copy copyService = new Copy())
    {
        copyService.PreAuthenticate = true;
        copyService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        copyService.Url = string.Format("{0}{1}", baseUrl, serviceUrl);

        copyService.Timeout = 600000;

        uint documentId = copyService.CopyIntoItems(destinationUrl , destinationUrlArray, fields, xmlByteArray, out resultsArray);
    }
}
```

When I execute the code I recieve the following error:

```
The request failed with the error message:
--
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/_forms/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_vti_bin%2fcopy.asmx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
--
```

It looks like I'm not authenticated and get redirected. The credentials however are correct.
Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

To be able to connect to SharePoint 2013 Online you have to attach the Office 365 authentication cookies as explained in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/14/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx) post.
My problem however is that there is also an ADFS involved. How can I autheticate against the ADFS?

Comment: You came to the right place to ask that. But allow me to suggest a sister site of Stack Overflow as well, as it's more Sharepoint oriented: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did you get this to work? I am very interested in seeing your solution. I have the same dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

This error most probably occurs due to incorrect authentication mode.
Since SharePoint Online (SPO) uses *claims-based authentication*,  [NetworkCredential Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can not be utilized for authentication in SPO. 
In order to perform the authentication against the ADFS in SPO you could utilize  [SharePointOnlineCredentials class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) from [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038).

### How to authenticate SharePoint Web Services in SharePoint Online (SPO)

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve authentication cookies:

```
private static CookieContainer GetAuthCookies(Uri webUri, string userName, string password)
{
    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (var c in password) { securePassword.AppendChar(c); }
    var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
    var authCookie = credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(webUri);
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    cookieContainer.SetCookies(webUri, authCookie);
    return cookieContainer;
}
```

### Example

```
string sourceUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx";
string destinationUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Documents/SharePoint User Guide 2013.docx";
FieldInformation[] fieldInfos;
CopyResult[] result;
byte[] fileContent;
using(var proxyCopy = new Copy())
{
     proxyCopy.Url = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx";
     proxyCopy.CookieContainer = GetAuthCookies(webUri, userName, password);

     proxyCopy.GetItem(sourceUrl,out fieldInfos,out fileContent);
     proxyCopy.CopyIntoItems(sourceUrl,new []{ destinationUrl}, fieldInfos, fileContent, out result);
 }
```

### References

- [Remote Authentication in SharePoint Online Using Claims-Based
  Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177.aspx)
- [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Comment: Hi Vadim. i'm sucessfully uploading files but while uploading large files i'm getting  operation timeout error.do you know how to increase timeout in web service?

Answer (score 0):

In my case (on premise) i have that error. when i changed at iis SharePoint authentication for web application , and disable "Forms Authentication". Now, i can´t enter to SharePoint by UI, but the Web Service works... So I have revert and I have been looking and...

[Paul stork] The Web Application for this site is running in Classic Mode rather than Claims mode.  This can happen if you create the web app using Powershell or upgrade from 2010.  You can use PowerShell to change it.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx

I have tried the Web Service in another new application created by UI in Central Administration (in same farm) and it had worked. The problem was the web application.

To try:
http://sharepointyankee.com/2011/01/04/the-request-failed-with-the-error-message-object-moved-sharepoint-2010-web-services-fba/
Extend your mixed authentication web application, and create a zone just for Windows Authentication, then change the Web Reference URL in the properties of your web service, to use that extended URL and port. You should have no issues of this kind anymore.