# Java Application to connect to sharepoint 2013 using webservices

Tags: java, sharepoint-2013, http-status-code-403

We are trying to write a standalone java application (got sample from web ) which will push the files from a source folder to a sharepoint location using published sharepoint webservices. 
Reason for using java is : This will be later plugged-in to another code.

Below are some points:

1. wsdl2java utility has generated java bindings for our sharepoint's copy service. 
    https://abc.sample.com/site1/_vti_bin/copy.asmx
2. Trying to use the generated stubs in my code to connect to sharepoint.

I getting below error

> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 403: Forbidden

This seems to be related with Sharepoint oline authentication mechanism. Given limitation I  cannot use C#, can anyone please help me in solving this problem in java. .

I could see similar C# example... but not sure if such functions are readily available in java.

[Upload document to Sharepoint 2013 Online using webservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836306/upload-document-to-sharepoint-2013-online-using-webservices)

Comment: This link give you the answer http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078906/enterprise-java/java-tip-consuming-sharepoint-web-services-with-a-java-client.html

Comment: Unfortunately, This does not answer connection to sharepoint2013 authentication issue

Comment: check this link http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140474/how-to-create-a-folder-in-sharepoint-using-java-and-restful-api

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to this project i've created as i think it will save you a lot of time in this tasks. I faced up similar problems and was not able to find a working solution, so i created this rest api wrapper fort he sharepoint online rest api v1 (not fully implemented)

https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java